# C2DM with App Engine Python returns 401 error

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, android-c2dm

I'm tyring to send a message to my mobile. Via browser I call the method that does this operation, I've logged the registrationId, authToken, etc.. and this is correct, because I tested in a local server and the message has been send to my phone using these keys.

**However on App Engine, I have a 401 error on the result of the `urlfetch.fetch` for '`https://android.clients.google.com/c2dm/send`'**.

Or if this is a problem with authentication. I doubt it is the problem above, because the method is called, and the error happens right in the end of the method in my App Engine server.

Here is how I make the request to the C2DM servers:

```
params = {
          'registration_id':registrationId,
          'collapse_key':0,
          'data.payload':encoded_msg
         }

        paramsByte = urllib.urlencode(params)
        logging.info(registrationId)

        url = 'https://android.clients.google.com/c2dm/send'
        logging.info(token)
        result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url,
                                payload=paramsByte,
                                method=urlfetch.POST,
                                headers={'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                         'Authorization':'GoogleLogin auth='+token}
                                )
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

> Now the client is running in a hosting server as suggested, and the
>   401 error happens when contacting
>   'https://android.clients.google.com/c2dm/send'.

However when using the following command on terminal with the same token and regId, it works.

> curl --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=your_authenticationid" 
>     "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send" -d
>   registration_id=your_registration     -d "data.payload=payload" -d
>   collapse_key=0

**Client code calling the method in server:**

```
$.getJSON('http://myapp.appspot.com/method?userId='+userId+'&message='+theMessage+'&callback=?', 
    function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

**Full method code for server:**

```
class PushHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

    '''This method sends the message to C2DM server to send the message to the phone'''
    def get(self):
        logging.info('aqui dentro')
        userId = self.request.get('userId')
        message = self.request.get('message')
        callback = self.request.get('callback')
        token = getToken(self) #this is a method I've implemented to get the token from C2DM servers by passing the SenderId and Password
        registrationId = ''
        contactNumber = ''

        # Get the registrationId to send to the C2DM server to know which 
        # device it may send the message
        regQuery = C2DMUser.all()
        regQuery.filter('userId =', int(userId))
        for k in regQuery:
            registrationId = k.registrationId

        # Builds the json to be sent to the phone
        record_to_json = {
                          'userId':userId,
                          'message':message
                          }
        data = []
        data.append(record_to_json)
        jsondata = simplejson.dumps(data) # Creates the json

        # Encode the JSON String
        u = unicode(jsondata, "utf-8")
        encoded_msg = u.encode("utf-8")

        params = {
                  'registration_id':registrationId,
                  'collapse_key':0,
                  'data.payload':encoded_msg
                  }

        paramsByte = urllib.urlencode(params)

        url = 'https://android.clients.google.com/c2dm/send'
        logging.info(token)
        result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url,
                                payload=paramsByte,
                                method=urlfetch.POST,
                                headers={'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                         'Authorization':'GoogleLogin auth='+token}
                                )

        data = []
        params_key = { 'status_code':result.status_code }
        data.append(params_key)
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        jsondata = simplejson.dumps(data)

        if result.status_code == 200:
            logging.info(result.status_code)
            self.response.out.write('' + callback + '(' + jsondata + ')') # handle the JSONP
        else:
            logging.info(result.status_code)
            self.response.out.write(result.status_code)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to load something from localhost on appspot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package name of your code must match the one you gave when you signed up for the c2dm account. For Java, if you gave com.myapp when you signed up, your c2dm calls must occur within that package. Not sure how this translates to Python, though.

Comment: Make sure you don't have a stale registration ID. If your code is storing credentials in the Datastore, you may want to delete and refresh them. I've encountered this before when using multiple accounts for testing.

Comment: But the package name is not used in my python server. I just use the application package name in the sign up form, which is the package name of my android application, not my server's package name. Is this right?

Comment: Correct, it's the Android package name.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the C2DM part is concerned, everything seems okay. If you are saying that with the same credentials it works with your local server, I am guessing that it should work on App Engine.

As far as the XMLHttpRequest error is concerned, you can't issue requests through the XMLHttpRequest to other domains or sub-domains. So, you cannot issue your request from localhost to `yourSite`. A solution would be using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Comment: Well, I'm using JSONP. My AppEngine server returns a JSON wrapped in a callback. Do you think I should try making calling my server not from localhost, but from my website online?

Comment: Yes. I'm assuming that this might be the problem. If you search on stackOverflow with the `XMLHttpRequest cannot load` error you will find the same answer as I provided you with. I'm assuming that this might be the only possible explication, since you've said that it worked on your local server.

Comment: I've uploaded my web client to a hosting server, and made a call, but 401 error still persists. Please check the UPDATE on my question with the full code of the method in server, and the call being made via jQuery on client. And the Same Origin Policy is not showing any more after I uploaded and used getJSON in client and get in server, but still the 401 error on server. =(